# how to decrease time needed to find numerical solution of a single nonlinear equation [sympy]

Tags: python, sympy, physics, trigonometry, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function that draws a line based on input values (which are all floats) and finds a numerical value for B_slv using the sympy function 'nsolve'. The value it finds is correct, but the calculation time is too high as the number of function calls is also high. Is there a way to improve the speed of this calculation? Sacrificing precision for speed is not an issue in many cases.

```
def cord_line_function(x1,y1,x2,y2, H, w, accuracy, B_old):

    from sympy import symbols, nsolve, cosh, solve
    from numpy import linspace, sinh
    from numpy import cosh as npcosh
    # Solve for B . Start with the initial estimation B_old in the iterative process:
    if not(isnan(B_old)):
        B_estimate = B_old
    else:
        B_estimate = -0.5*(x2-x1)
        B     = symbols('B')
        B_slv = float(nsolve((H/w * (cosh(w*(x1+B)/H)-1) - y1) - (H/w * 
    (cosh(w*(x2+B)/H)-1) - y2), B, B_estimate, quick = True))
    # return a function based on the found values:
    x = linspace(float(x1), float(x2), int((x2-x1)*accuracy))
    y = H/w * (npcosh(w*(x+B_slv)/H)-1)

    # since the first point of the graph is set as 0, we know that y_real = y - y[0]
    y = y - y[0]

    # The cord length would be given by L:
    # L = Σ sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) = ∫sqrt(1 + (dy/dx)^2)dx
    # Since y = H/w * (cosh(w*(x+B)/H)-1) - A
    # dy/dx = sinh(w*(x+B)/H)
    # gives: L =      ∫sqrt(1+(sinh(w*(x+B)/H))^2) dx
    #          =      ∫sqrt(1+(sinh(w*u    /H))^2) du      with u = B+x   ;     du = dx
    #          = H/w  ∫sqrt(1+(sinh(s)        )^2) ds      with s=w*u/H   ;     ds = w/H * du
    #          = H/w  ∫sqrt(   cosh(s)         ^2) ds
    #          = H/w  ∫        cosh(s)             ds
    #          = H/w  *        sinh(s) + Constant
    s1 = w*(x1+B_slv)/H
    s2 = w*(x2+B_slv)/H
    length = H/w * sinh(s2) - H/w * sinh(s1)

    return [x, y, length, B_slv]
```

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/solving/solve-numerically.html talks about alternatives to `nsolve`.  One is to use the `mpmath` solver directly, with more control parameters.  `scipy` and `numpy` have numeric solvers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has stated that the input values are not sympy symbols, but rather standard python `float`s.

As such, and building on Oscar Benjamin's answer, we can state that in order to speed up the code, you should solve your equation once to get a closed-form solution, and then turn this closed-form solution into a function which can be numerically calculated (rather than symbolically).

In code:

```py
from sympy import symbols, solve, cosh, exp, lambdify,
H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2, B = symbols('H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2, B')
eq = (H/w * (cosh(w*(x1+B)/H)-1) - y1) - (H/w * (cosh(w*(x2+B)/H)-1) - y2)
sol = solve(eq.rewrite(exp).expand(), B)
# this will produce a numerically evaluated function from the solution
numerical_function = lambdify((H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2), sol)

... 
# call the created function later as you would a normal function
B_slv_1, B_slv_2 = numerical_function(H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

In fact, if we're smart about it, we can make it even faster by specifying the correct module. By default, `lambdaify` is will use `numpy`, which is optimised for vector-like computations. However, here we're dealing with scalar inputs, so the native python `math` module would be faster! Thankfully, we can easily tell `lambdaify` to switch to the `math` module using the `modules` keyword.

To illustrate the speedup we get, we can use the `timeit` module :

```
from timeit import timeit
setup = '''
from sympy import symbols, solve, nsolve, cosh, exp, Eq, lambdify, nsolve

def calculation_function_factory(module):
    H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2, B = symbols('H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2, B')
    eq: Eq = (H/w * (cosh(w*(x1+B)/H)-1) - y1) - \
        (H/w * (cosh(w*(x2+B)/H)-1) - y2)

    s1, s2 = solve(eq.rewrite(exp).expand(), B)
    return lambdify((H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2), s1, modules=module)


calculation_mt = calculation_function_factory("math")
calculation_np = calculation_function_factory("numpy")


def symbolic_solve(H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2):
    B = symbols('B')
    B_estimate = -0.5*(x2-x1)
    return float(nsolve(
        (H/w * (cosh(w*(x1+B)/H)-1) - y1) - (H/w * (cosh(w*(x2+B)/H)-1) - y2),
        B,
        B_estimate,
        quick=True))

'''

calc_m = "calculation_mt(1,2,3,4,5,6)"
calc_n = "calculation_np(1,2,3,4,5,6)"
solv = "symbolic_solve(1,2,3,4,5,6)"

ITER = 1000

t_solve = timeit(solv, setup=setup, number=ITER)
print(t_solve) # >>> 2.0169183000107296 seconds for ITER iterations
t_calc_n = timeit(calc_n, setup=setup, number=ITER)
print(t_calc_n) # >>> 0.013456200002110563 seconds for ITER iterations
t_calc_m = timeit(calc_m, setup=setup, number=ITER)
print(t_calc_m) # >>> 0.00293279999459628 seconds for ITER iterations
```

Comment: Incredible! I never expected so much improvement! Thank a lot, but I wonder what happens here:

    s1, s2 = solve(eq.rewrite(exp).expand(), B)
    return lambdify((H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2), s1, modules=module)

I would expect that these would be the output of s1 and s2, but I do not see their functions and I get the value for B_slv as output. This is actually the output that I want, but I still want to know why s1 and s2 are stated there. 

Could you please explain this?

Comment: [lambdaify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) returns a callable function object based on the expression passed to it. This function object will return a numerical result (or a tuple of numerical results) when called. In the code above, i called the symbolic solutions returned by `solve()`: `s1` and `s2`. When numerically evaluated though `lambdaify`, these give `B_slv_1` and `B_slv_2`, respecitvely (see first code block). I only evaluated `s1` in the benchmark code, since this was what you had in your original code.

Comment: Thanks again! It seems I  am not completely finished this this however. In a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76505684/converting-sympy-symbolic-solve-to-numeric-solve?noredirect=1#comment134895082_76505684) I want to convert a similar piece of code, according to your example. This does not fully work however. It would be much appreciated if you could help.

Answer (score 3):

This particular equation can be solved symbolically by SymPy:

```
In [56]: H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2, B = symbols('H, w, x1, x2, y1, y2, B')

In [57]: eq = (H/w * (cosh(w*(x1+B)/H)-1) - y1) - (H/w * (cosh(w*(x2+B)/H)-1) - y2)

In [58]: eq
Out[58]: 
  ⎛    ⎛w⋅(B + x₁)⎞    ⎞     ⎛    ⎛w⋅(B + x₂)⎞    ⎞          
H⋅⎜cosh⎜──────────⎟ - 1⎟   H⋅⎜cosh⎜──────────⎟ - 1⎟          
  ⎝    ⎝    H     ⎠    ⎠     ⎝    ⎝    H     ⎠    ⎠          
──────────────────────── - ──────────────────────── - y₁ + y₂
           w                          w                      

In [59]: eq.rewrite(exp).expand()
Out[59]: 
   B⋅w  w⋅x₁      B⋅w  w⋅x₂      -B⋅w   -w⋅x₂       -B⋅w   -w⋅x₁           
   ───  ────      ───  ────      ─────  ──────      ─────  ──────          
    H    H         H    H          H      H           H      H             
H⋅ℯ   ⋅ℯ       H⋅ℯ   ⋅ℯ       H⋅ℯ     ⋅ℯ         H⋅ℯ     ⋅ℯ                
──────────── - ──────────── - ──────────────── + ──────────────── - y₁ + y₂
    2⋅w            2⋅w              2⋅w                2⋅w                 

In [60]: s1, s2 = solve(eq.rewrite(exp).expand(), B)

In [61]: print(s1)
H*log(w*(y1 - y2)/(H*(exp(w*x1/H) - exp(w*x2/H))) - sqrt((H**2*exp(2*w*x1/H) - 2*H**2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H) + H**2*exp(2*w*x2/H) + w**2*y1**2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H) - 2*w**2*y1*y2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H) + w**2*y2**2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H))*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H))*exp(-w*x1/H)*exp(-w*x2/H)/(H*(exp(w*x1/H) - exp(w*x2/H))))/w

In [62]: print(s2)
H*log(w*(y1 - y2)/(H*(exp(w*x1/H) - exp(w*x2/H))) + sqrt((H**2*exp(2*w*x1/H) - 2*H**2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H) + H**2*exp(2*w*x2/H) + w**2*y1**2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H) - 2*w**2*y1*y2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H) + w**2*y2**2*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H))*exp(w*x1/H)*exp(w*x2/H))*exp(-w*x1/H)*exp(-w*x2/H)/(H*(exp(w*x1/H) - exp(w*x2/H))))/w
```

You can just copy paste those solution expressions into your code or otherwise use lambdify to evaluate the expressions efficiently.

Here `solve` finds two solutions. I am not sure how the two different solutions relate to your original problem but presumably one of them is the one that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! But will this give a faster result? I am not too experienced with sympy, but it sounds to me that rewriting does not optimise this, but maybe I am wrong.
Also, it seems to me that you assumed unknown variables for input variables. These are actually known numbers and do not have to be used as symbols. i will update this in the question.

Comment: a closed-form mathematical function will almost always be faster than trying to symbolically solve something. In this case, it's about 500 to1000 times faster... I'll post an answer with the relevant code

Comment: In one of my projects I need to do something similar to you, where I need to solve some couple equations that aren't in a neat closed form from the start. To increase the speed, I do similar things as @TimMoore suggested, and then write the closed form `sympy` function into another file as a `numpy` function that's decorated with `numba`. Doing this before solving is many orders of magnitude faster than reevaluating the same `sympy` math for different parameters over and over. Then again, it is a brute-forced method, but having access to the symbolic math can be advantageous.